# Cassandra 1.2 merging data from memtables and sstables takes too long

Tags: cassandra

Here is a trace from a 4 node cassandra cluster, running 1.2.6.  I'm seeing a timeout with a simple select when the cluster is under no load and I need some help getting to the bottom of it.

```
 activity                                                                | timestamp    | source        | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------
                                                      execute_cql3_query | 05:21:00,848 | 100.69.176.51 |              0
 Parsing select * from user_scores where user_id='26257166' LIMIT 10000; | 05:21:00,848 | 100.69.176.51 |             77
                                                      Peparing statement | 05:21:00,848 | 100.69.176.51 |            225
                         Executing single-partition query on user_scores | 05:21:00,849 | 100.69.176.51 |            589
                                            Acquiring sstable references | 05:21:00,849 | 100.69.176.51 |            626
                                             Merging memtable tombstones | 05:21:00,849 | 100.69.176.51 |            676
                                            Key cache hit for sstable 34 | 05:21:00,849 | 100.69.176.51 |            817
                             Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 05:21:00,849 | 100.69.176.51 |            836
                                            Key cache hit for sstable 32 | 05:21:00,849 | 100.69.176.51 |           1135
                             Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 05:21:00,849 | 100.69.176.51 |           1153
                              Merging data from memtables and 2 sstables | 05:21:00,850 | 100.69.176.51 |           1394
                                                        Request complete | 05:21:20,881 | 100.69.176.51 |       20033807
```

Here is the schema.  You can see that is includes a few collections.

```
create table user_scores
(
    user_id varchar,
    post_type varchar,
    score double,
    team_to_score_map map<varchar, double>,
    affiliation_to_score_map map<varchar, double>,
    campaign_to_score_map map<varchar, double>,
    person_to_score_map map<varchar, double>,
    primary key(user_id, post_type)
)
with compaction =
{
  'class' : 'LeveledCompactionStrategy',
  'sstable_size_in_mb' : 10
};
```

I added the leveled compaction strategy as it was supposed to help with read latency.

I'd like to understand what could cause the cluster to timeout during the merge phase.  Not all queries timeout.  It appears to happen more frequently with rows that have maps with a larger number of entries.

Here is another trace of a failure for good measure.  It is very reproducable:

```
 activity                                                                | timestamp    | source         | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------
                                                      execute_cql3_query | 05:51:34,557 |  100.69.176.51 |              0
                                    Message received from /100.69.176.51 | 05:51:34,195 | 100.69.184.134 |            102
                         Executing single-partition query on user_scores | 05:51:34,199 | 100.69.184.134 |           3512
                                            Acquiring sstable references | 05:51:34,199 | 100.69.184.134 |           3741
                                             Merging memtable tombstones | 05:51:34,199 | 100.69.184.134 |           3890
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 5 | 05:51:34,199 | 100.69.184.134 |           4040
                             Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 05:51:34,199 | 100.69.184.134 |           4059
                              Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables | 05:51:34,200 | 100.69.184.134 |           4412
 Parsing select * from user_scores where user_id='26257166' LIMIT 10000; | 05:51:34,558 |  100.69.176.51 |             91
                                                      Peparing statement | 05:51:34,558 |  100.69.176.51 |            238
                               Enqueuing data request to /100.69.184.134 | 05:51:34,558 |  100.69.176.51 |            567
                                      Sending message to /100.69.184.134 | 05:51:34,558 |  100.69.176.51 |            979
                                                        Request complete | 05:51:54,562 |  100.69.176.51 |       20005209
```

And a trace from when it works:

```
 activity                                                                 | timestamp    | source         | source_elapsed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------
                                                       execute_cql3_query | 05:55:07,772 |  100.69.176.51 |              0
                                     Message received from /100.69.176.51 | 05:55:07,408 | 100.69.184.134 |             53
                          Executing single-partition query on user_scores | 05:55:07,409 | 100.69.184.134 |           1014
                                             Acquiring sstable references | 05:55:07,409 | 100.69.184.134 |           1087
                                              Merging memtable tombstones | 05:55:07,410 | 100.69.184.134 |           1209
                       Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 5 | 05:55:07,410 | 100.69.184.134 |           1681
                              Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 05:55:07,410 | 100.69.184.134 |           1732
                               Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables | 05:55:07,411 | 100.69.184.134 |           2415
                                       Read 1 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 05:55:07,412 | 100.69.184.134 |           3274
                                     Enqueuing response to /100.69.176.51 | 05:55:07,412 | 100.69.184.134 |           3534
                                        Sending message to /100.69.176.51 | 05:55:07,412 | 100.69.184.134 |           3936
 Parsing select * from user_scores where user_id='305722020' LIMIT 10000; | 05:55:07,772 |  100.69.176.51 |             96
                                                       Peparing statement | 05:55:07,772 |  100.69.176.51 |            262
                                Enqueuing data request to /100.69.184.134 | 05:55:07,773 |  100.69.176.51 |            600
                                       Sending message to /100.69.184.134 | 05:55:07,773 |  100.69.176.51 |            847
                                    Message received from /100.69.184.134 | 05:55:07,778 |  100.69.176.51 |           6103
                                 Processing response from /100.69.184.134 | 05:55:07,778 |  100.69.176.51 |           6341
                                                         Request complete | 05:55:07,778 |  100.69.176.51 |           6780
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was running into a performance issue with 1.2.  Fortunately a patch had just been applied to the 1.2 branch, so when I built from source my problem went away.

see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5677 for a detailed explanation.